# How to read Facebook App links from Branch SDK

Tags: unity-game-engine, branch.io

I want to use deep link in my FaceBook ads install campaign.

According to Branch docs: https://docs.branch.io/deep-linked-ads/facebook-app-install-ads/#optional-deep-link-your-app-install-campaign

> Unfortunately, we've found that the direct S2S mechanism for retrieving deep links is rather unreliable. We recommend that you have the Facebook Android / iOS SDKs installed so Branch can work directly with them on the client side for the best outcome.

I need to integrate Facebook SDK and then call:

```
Branch.getAutoInstance(this).enableFacebookAppLinkCheck();
```

But this method is not exist in Unity Plugin (https://docs.branch.io/apps/unity/)

Any ideas how to overcome that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have a wrapper for this method call. Please call the code from the Native Android files.